# JS. Как протестировать набор номера телефона?

Tags: javascript, android, html

На сайте есть ссылка типа `tel:+349294923`, при клике на которую с моб. устройства этот номер набирается и скрипт `mango.js` срабатывает. Но это можно сделать только с телефона, ибо с ПК просто не получается проверить. Был вариант - включить синхронизацию на устройствах, но я часа два с ней бился - не получается.
Есть ли еще способ протестировать/иммитировать набор номера?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но Скайп может обработать tel:

Comment: Возможно вам нужны эмуляторы смартфонов, попробуйте Genymotion

Comment: @DenisI скайп только при балансе)

Comment: @VladOrlinskas включил порты и поднял сервер в пределах роутера, мне помогло.

Думаю тему можно закрыть